# firebase.database reference not working

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to use firebase realtime database in my ionic project. For some reason I'm not able to access the database after initializing the firebase app. I have added firebase-app and firebase-database CDNs and still it doesn't seem to work.
head tag of my index.html looks like:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "api-key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the functionality that I'm trying to implement is that I'm using a modal to submit a form which has addRide method on click:

```
 .controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth();
  var dref = firebase.database().ref().child("rides");
  $scope.rides = $firebaseArray(dref);
  $scope.addRide = function(){
    $scope.rides.$add({
      //object
    })
   }
  })
```

EDIT:

It worked after I separated the modal controller from its parent page. I'm able to add the object using add but for some reason the webstorm intellisense is still not picking up database().

Comment: 1) `api-key, domain, url and bucket` are your firebase's data?
2) Can you show how you try to use firebase in js and how it fails? Do you get any error?

Comment: I believe he covered those so we could not see them. But yes, please provide any errors and the code you are trying to access `firebase` with.

Comment: Edited the post with more details!

Comment: Add Firebase to your controller: .controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseArray, Firebase)

Comment: Are you suggesting this as per their latest 3.x SDK? Because they gave up on the 'Firebase' constructor in latest update.

Comment: @Sagar I still do it like that in an 3.x project and it works so can't hurt to try. You only have to add 1 word and run it and if it doesn't work then we know that isn't the problem.

Comment: No luck by adding 'Firebase' to controller as expected!

Comment: At which line it throws error? And which error? Is it only a webstorm error?